# Facing problem while installing yappi python package on windows operating system

Tags: python

**I am getting this error**

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\zeeshan\anaconda3\envs\Asynchronous-Federated-Learning-on-Hierarchical-Clusters-main\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\zeeshan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xiek07re\\yappi_551fe7f7acf5495c84fb479ceef068c2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\zeeshan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-xiek07re\\yappi_551fe7f7acf5495c84fb479ceef068c2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\zeeshan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-cp94mqyn'
       cwd: C:\Users\zeeshan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xiek07re\yappi_551fe7f7acf5495c84fb479ceef068c2\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying yappi\yappi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_yappi' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yappi
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error? Important part:

extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

So go to the link. Download Microsoft Visual C++ 14 or greater. Install it and then try installing yappi again.